# How to fix the error "unable to open socket file" in VisualVM to profile memory of my application?

Tags: apache-flink, visualvm, jstack

Why am I getting the message "Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded" when I am trying to profiling memory using VisualVM? 
I am trying to profile Flink TaskManager. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38527209/2096986) says that I have to increase the timeout of VisualVM but the parameter `-Dsun.tools.attach.attachTimeout` does not work to start VisualVM with it.
I get the same or similar error when I try to dump the memory using jstack:

```
$ sudo jstack 700
700: Unable to open socket file /proc/700/root/tmp/.java_pid700: target process 700 doesn't respond within 10500ms or HotSpot VM not loaded
```

[image]

Comment: did you find the answer on how to solve this problem?

Comment: No, I switched to another profiler such as YourKit